# Iterating in Clojure over vectors

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

Given a vector, or possibly nested vector, how do you iterate a function in Clojure over the vector (nested vector) n times? Moreover, how can you output each level of iteration into a vector? Whereby the output vector starts with the initial conditions, namely the input vector (nested vector), followed by the subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `iterate`. It returns a lazy sequence of the iterations, starting with the input. So, for example:

```
(def init (range 10))

(take 3 (iterate #(map inc %) init)) 
;; gives ((0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11))
```

Comment: How could this be turned into a general function? I tried something similar before by replacing inc with f, 3 with n and init with a. So, I am inputting [a n f].

Comment: @Alex: It sounds like you've got it. What trouble are you having?